# Mysql inner join doesn't work on Mysql 5.1

Tags: php, mysql

It works correctly on my local server (MySql 5.5) but it doesn't work on remote server (MySql 5.1)

```
$dati = mysql_query(" 
    SELECT      * 
    FROM        $tb_liguria 
    JOIN        $tb_piemonte ON $tb_piemonte.piemonte_data = $tb_liguria.liguria_data
    JOIN        $tb_paca ON $tb_paca.paca_data = $tb_liguria.liguria_data
    JOIN        $tb_rhonealpes ON $tb_rhonealpes.rhonealpes_data = $tb_liguria.liguria_data
    WHERE       $tb_liguria.liguria_data >= '$dataInizio' and $tb_liguria.liguria_data <= '$dataFine'
    ORDER       BY $tb_liguria.liguria_data 
");
```

I also tried this but nothing has changed

```
$dati = mysql_query(" 
    SELECT      * 
    FROM        $tb_liguria 
    JOIN        ($tb_piemonte, $tb_paca, $tb_rhonealpes)
    ON          ($tb_liguria.liguria_data=$tb_piemonte.piemonte_data AND $tb_liguria.liguria_data=$tb_paca.paca_data AND $tb_liguria.liguria_data=$tb_rhonealpes.rhonealpes_data)
    WHERE       ($tb_liguria.liguria_data >= '$dataInizio' AND $tb_liguria.liguria_data <= '$dataFine')
    ORDER BY    $tb_liguria.liguria_data 
");
```

Comment: more then mysql. does your online server support mysql_* commands? those are deprecated. That said does it return errors?

Comment: Can you explain "but in doesn't work"? Any error message, unexpected result?

Comment: Use echo mysql_error($dati); and the MySQL server should tell you whats wrong incase your query has errors. You should also aware not to use mysql extension cause its deprecated, insecure, outdated, not performant and will be removed from PHP soon. Use MySQLi (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or even better PDO (php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: It returns this error:
" The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay "

Comment: if I remove two JOIN and I leave only the first one... it works!

On my local server with MySql 5.5 work fine.
The problem is only on remote server with MySql 5.1
So I don't think is a problem of deprecated functions

Comment: Then you have to change SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 in your my.ini as the errors says and you can join as many tables as you like. You should also set max_join_size = 30 or so and you will be fine

Comment: Pro tip: Avoid `SELECT *`, especially on big joins. It puts lots of redundant columns into your result set, which slows things down on your server and client. Instead, list the columns you need in the result set.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I am on a shared server and I can't change my.ini but I solved by setting the parameter with PHP.
I use `SELECT *` becouse every table has 3 columns and I need each of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

Adding this before the query:

```
$setupMySql = mysql_query(" SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1 " ) or die(mysql_error());
```